# Generating tabs with jquery and css

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make something like the bar at the bottom of GMail or Facebook's chat window. **I am NOT trying to make a chat service or anything in that like.**

In facebook's chat, when you click a friend, a rectangular block thingy forms at the bottom of the visible page and has your friends name on it as well as the chat history.

I was wondering hwo you can make it so that if u have a list, you can click each of those and generate tabs with the respective information of what you clicked at the bottom of your page?

Would I have to generate the tabs 1st for each one and then set display:none and then when I want to generate a tab, use [please forgive the poor syntax below]

```
$(##tab attribute##).click(function {
        ##selected tab##.show()
     }
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly... You don't have to create the tabs as you can create them on the fly. Have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8TMM/) for a trivial implementation.

**EDIT**

Updating with detail, as per AlienWebguy's suggestion:

First, create your ordered list of links and a container for your tabs. Each link has a unique id:

html:

```
<!-- links to contacts or whatever -->
<ul id="chat-links">
    <li><a id="foo" href="#">foo</a></li>
    <li><a id="bar" href="#">bar</a></li>
    <li><a id="baz" href="#">baz</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- container for your tabs -->
<div id="chat-stage"></div>
```

Then, create a click event for each link. Each click event will create a personalised message inside a 'chat-window' div:

jQuery:

```
// click event
$('#chat-links a').click(function() {
    // personalised message
    var str = "Hi, " + this.id + ", what's up?";
    // append a new div to your tab container
    $('#chat-stage').append('<div class="chat-window">' + str + '</div>');
});
```

Then style the elements:

css:

```
#chat-stage
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;  
}

.chat-window
{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 100px;  
}
```

As I mentioned this is a pretty trivial implemetation. For instance, this will allow you to click on the same link several times and open a new tab for each click event. You could amend the click event to deal with this; e.g: generate an id for each div and do a conditional. You might also want to minimise, or remove other tabs when opening a new tab. Again, your implementation depends on what you want to do; in the latter case you could add `$('#chat-stage').empty();` to the first line of your click event.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Please always post the result code as well as the fiddle link. If the link ever stops working, your answer will be useless to others.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Yes.. good point! not sure why I didn't do that in the first place; guess it was pretty late. answer updated. cheers.